# Subversion does not show .php files in web-frontend

Tags: svn

Subversion 1.7 doesn´t show php files in the web frontend (file not found). Every other extension (ini, bmp, txt, ...) works. There are no issues with subversion clients (Netbeans etc.) Commit and Checkout works.
Any Ideas?

kind regards

Comment: Are you sure they are versioned?

Comment: Yes, they are. I restored a repo from a dump. All other file extensions work.

Comment: The problem is solved. It seems that there are some issues with php-fpm.
As I switched back to fastcgi, everything worked as it should.